# error: constructor complex in class complex cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

```
class complex {
    int a,b;

    void complex(int x,int y)
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
    }
    void complex()
    {
        System.out.println(a+"+ i"+b);
    }
}
```

...

```
class Main {
 public static void main (String[] args) 
 {
    complex n1 = new complex(10,20);
    complex n2 = new complex(30,40);
    n1.complex();
    n2.complex();
 }
}
```

The above code raises the following build error:

> constructor complex in class complex cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: `void complex(int x,int y)` is not a constructor. Remove the `void` to make it a constructor.

Comment: And follow Java code standards by naming your class `Complex` with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor does should not 'return' a type. Update the access level. Use a different name than the class name for methods.

For example:

```
class complex
{
  int a,b;

  public complex(int x,int y)
  {
    a=x;
    b=y;
  }

  public void display()
  {
    System.out.println(a+"+ i"+b);
  }
}
```

...

```
class Main {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    complex n1 = new complex(10, 20);
    complex n2 = new complex(30, 40);
    n1.display();
    n2.display();
  }
}
```